# Reset component state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm really struggling to reset the state back to it's orginal from with a method in React. My current reset method only resets the value. I have tried adding in const equal to the original state and then setting state equal to that, but I have had no luck.

Any advice?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
      c.value = 0;
      return c;
    });
    this.setState({ counters: counters });
  };
}
```

Comment: It's a not valid JS code. Please take a look at brackets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could keep the initial state in a separate array, and create a copy of the array as initial state, and also create a copy of the array when using the `handleReset`.

**Example**

```js
const counters = [
  { id: 1, value: 4 },
  { id: 2, value: 0 },
  { id: 3, value: 0 },
  { id: 4, value: 0 }
];

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [...counters]
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({ counters: [...counters] });
  };

  handleClick = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const counters = [...prevState.counters];

      counters[index] = {
        ...counters[index],
        value: counters[index].value + 1
      };

      return { counters };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map((counter, index) => (
          <button id={counter.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}>
            {counter.value}
          </button>
        ))}
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have known this. I was trying to put the counters array inside of the handleReset method instead of placing it globally. Do you know why it didn't work when I put it inside of the method?

EDIT: nevermind, it works just fine actually. I must have had a syntax error or something. Anyway, thank you for your code. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Not known to many, changing the `key` prop is one way to reset a component's state. When the `key` of an element changes, React will unmount it and reinstantiate the component.

If your component has a parent component and could get the parent component to change the `key` on your component. In the example below, the parent component has a `key` state that is a number. When you click the reset button, the parent component increases the `key` and the `Counter` component is remounted, thereby clearing all state. Any different value of `key` will cause the component to remount.

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 4 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ],
  };
  
  handleClick = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const counters = [...prevState.counters];

      counters[index] = {
        ...counters[index],
        value: counters[index].value + 1
      };

      return { counters };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map((counter, index) => (
          <button id={counter.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}>
            {counter.value}
          </button>
        ))}
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.props.handleReset}>Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    key: 0,
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ 
      key: prevState.key + 1 
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter 
          key={this.state.key} 
          handleReset={this.handleReset}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the assumption that your state is valid JSON, this seems a simple solution:

```
const initialState = {...};

class ... {
    this.state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState));

    reset = () => {
        this.setState(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState)));
    }
}
```

Deep cloning, no libs needed, native code.