# Resetting input field (controlled component) in a nested state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-state-management

I am working on a nested state. And after a certain event(on form submit), I want to reset the form input field to the initial state, and also its flags(for a controlled component). But I am not able to that.

My **initial State** looks like this:

```
state = {
orderForm: {
  name: {
    elementType: "input",
    elementConfig: {
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Your Name",
    },
    value: "",
    validation: {
      required: true,
    },
    valid: false,
  },
  address: {
    elementType: "input",
    elementConfig: {
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Your Address",
    },
    value: "",
    validation: {
      required: true,
    },
    valid: false,
    touched: false,
  },
  email: {
    elementType: "input",
    elementConfig: {
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Your Email",
    },
    value: "",
    validation: {
      required: true,
    },
    valid: false,
    touched: false,
  },
  mobile: {
    elementType: "input",
    elementConfig: {
      type: "text",
      placeholder: "Your Phone",
    },
    value: "",
    validation: {
      required: true,
      length: true,
    },
    valid: false,
    touched: false,
  },
  addressType: {
    elementType: "select",
    elementConfig: {
      options: [
        { value: "home", displayValue: "Residental" },
        { value: "office", displayValue: "Commerical" },
      ],
    },
    value: "home",
    validation: {
      required: false,
    },
    valid: true,
  },
},
formIsValid: false,
};
```

And when I submit my it looks like,

```
{
"orderForm": {
"name": {
  "elementType": "input",
  "elementConfig": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholder": "Your Name"
  },
  "value": "abc",
  "validation": {
    "required": true
  },
  "valid": true,
  "touched": true
},
"address": {
  "elementType": "input",
  "elementConfig": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholder": "Your Address"
  },
  "value": "123 - xyz",
  "validation": {
    "required": true
  },
  "valid": true,
  "touched": true
},
"email": {
  "elementType": "input",
  "elementConfig": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholder": "Your Email"
  },
  "value": "a@bc.com",
  "validation": {
    "required": true
  },
  "valid": true,
  "touched": true
},
"mobile": {
  "elementType": "input",
  "elementConfig": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholder": "Your Phone"
  },
  "value": "1234567890",
  "validation": {
    "required": true,
    "length": true
  },
  "valid": true,
  "touched": true
},
"addressType": {
  "elementType": "select",
  "elementConfig": {
    "options": [
      {
        "value": "home",
        "displayValue": "Residental"
      },
      {
        "value": "office",
        "displayValue": "Commerical"
      }
    ]
  },
  "value": "office",
  "validation": {
    "required": false
  },
  "valid": true,
  "touched": true
}
},
"formIsValid": true
}
```

So I tried this method, which I tried to reset it using the previous state but I am not able to do it. I know I can do it by storing it in a variable see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51830813/8550761) but don't want to use this. And using the Spread operator for making copies for each is too much tedious.

my method which I tried, it's not working.

```
this.setState(
        (prevState) => {
          const orderForm = [...prevState.orderForm];
          return { orderForm };
        },
        () => {this.props.history.push("/orders")}
      );
```

I know there could be better way to that. And I don't want to use any helper library.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work,

```
this.setState(prevState=>({
return {
   ...prevState,
   // spread your initial state.
 }),()=>console.log(your state));
```

Now there can be different scenarios, I don't if your state is at your component level or at redux level. But in both ways you can access your initial state. If it's at component level, it's pretty easy.

If you're using redux, then you can make use of Selectors and get your initial state as props from your redux or any other state management library you're using.